# Problem with using conditionals inside template literals

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements, literals, ternary

How can I make ternary operator work if I have the following codes?

```
'<p>{balance==0?<span class="danger">Not available</span>:(Stock: {balance}})</p>'
```

Thank you!

---

Sorry about that, maybe my question is not clear. Let me elaborate more here I'm using Bloodhound library to provide a suggestion drop down list.
And the code as shown as below.

```
var prodName_typehead = {
              name: 'prod_name',
              displayKey: 'name',
              hint: (App.isRTL() ? false : true),
              source: item.ttAdapter(),
              limit: 20,
              templates: {
                suggestion: Handlebars.compile([
                  '<div class="media">',
                        '<div class="pull-left">',
                            '<div class="media-object">',
                                '<img src="{{thumb}}" width="50" height="50"/>',
                            '</div>',
                        '</div>',
                        '<div class="media-body">',
                            '<p><strong>{{name}}</strong></p>',
                            '<p>{{desc}}</p>',
                            `<p>${balance==0 ? `<span class="danger">Not available</span>`:`(Stock: ${balance})`}</p>`,
                        '</div>',
                  '</div>',
                ].join(''))
              }
            };
```

Comment: This is not valid JavaScript. Could you elaborate?

Comment: user ` instead of '
and add a $ before each {

Comment: @A.Chiesa: that looks like valid JavaScript, although it's a string and not a template-literal.

Comment: @A.Chiesa Why is this _"not valid JavaScript"_? o.O That's just a plain old string literal

Comment: @DavidsaysreinstateMonica, Andreas. Yes you are both right. I meant something different: what is inside the string is not JavaScript code, is just a string. And, if you consider what's inside the string as code, it's not valid. I short circuited all of this and came out with something not true. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Try like below.

```
`<p>${balance==0 ? `<span class="danger">Not available</span>`:`(Stock: ${balance})`}</p>`
```

Check below results for `balance = 0` & `balance = 1`.

```js
let balance = 0;
let result = `<p>${balance==0 ? `<span class="danger">Not available</span>`:`(Stock: ${balance})`}</p>`;
console.log('balance = 0 ->', result);

balance = 1;
result = `<p>${balance==0 ? `<span class="danger">Not available</span>`:`(Stock: ${balance})`}</p>`;
console.log('balance = 1 ->', result);
```

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: balance is not defined - appeared error.

Comment: Then you have to define `balance` variable before using.

Comment: I'm using Bloodhound library, call ajax to return the balance value.